# How to put jQuery code AFTER jQuery includes?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I need to call some jQuery code during Wordpress plugin development.

jQuery include function is:

```
function jQueryInclude() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-mouse');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-autocomplete');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-selectmenu');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider');
}
```

jQuery code function is:

```
function jQueryCode() {
    echo <<< 'EOS'

    <script type="application/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            //
        });

        function test_connection() {
            var URL = $('#URL').val(); // id exists!
            alert(URL);
        }
    </script>

    EOS;
}
```

So let's combine it together:

### Case 1:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_script', function() {
    jQueryInclude();
});

add_action('admin_footer', function() {
    jQueryCode();
});
```

Whole HTML looks like:

- Include at end (ok)
- jQuery code before includes at end (bad)

Execution results (when press button with `onclick=test_connection();`) are errors:

- jQuery not defined
- $ is not a function

### Case 2:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_script', function() {
    jQueryInclude();
    jQueryCode();
});
```

Whole HTML looks like:

- Include at end (ok)
- jQuery code jumps to head section (what???)

Execution results - same errors as before

### Case 3:

```
add_action('admin_footer', function() {
    jQueryInclude();
    jQueryCode();
});
```

HTML and errors - same as for **Case 1**.

---

How to correctly combine jQuery includes and some jQuery code in Wordpress plugin code?

Comment: You need to make custom js file for custom JS code.
Check this link for more info https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-add-jquery-scripts-to-wordpress Hope now you will get solution for it

Comment: No, these advices didn't work. They mostly about themes. I know how to work with jQuery in themes

Comment: use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: Seems, Wordpress HTML creation engine doesn't like inline script.

Comment: Just add enqueuing external (!) JS code and everything become to work good

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in inline script. Wordpress, guess, doesn't like it.

I changed jQueryCode() body to:

```
wp_enqueue_script('itilium_test', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/js/itilium-test.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
```

and code works fine